# Smooth confidence intervals and point estimated in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, point

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(RR = c(0.89, 0.9, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 
0.98, 0.99, 1, 1.01, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.08, 1.09, 1.11, 
1.12, 1.13, 1.15), CI.upper = c(1, 1, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 
1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.08, 1.1, 1.12, 1.13, 1.16, 1.18, 
1.21, 1.23, 1.25, 1.29), CI.lower = c(0.78, 0.8, 0.83, 0.85, 
0.87, 0.89, 0.9, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.98, 0.98, 0.98, 0.99, 
1, 1, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01), quan_demands = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 
20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 
100)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

I am plotting RR and their respective confidence intervals but I cannot seem to find a way to make the lines that runs across the points and the confidence intervals smoother.

I have tried to use geom_smooth and stat_smooth with no luck.

My code is this one:

```
ggplot(data = data, aes(x= quan_demands, y = RR)) + 
geom_point(size = 1, shape = 19, color = "darkblue") + 
geom_line(size = 0.5, colour = "darkblue") +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = CI.lower, ymax = CI.upper), linetype = 2, alpha = 0.4, fill = 
"deepskyblue3") +
theme_bw() + 
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), 
                 breaks = seq(0, 100, 25)) +
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.75, 1.4), 
                 breaks = seq(0, 1.5, 0.2)) +
geom_vline(xintercept = 45, color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
geom_hline(yintercept = 1, color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1),
    axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
    axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12),
    plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "mm"),
    strip.background = element_rect(fill = "deepskyblue3", size = 1),
    strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "white", size = 13)) +
facet_grid(. ~ "title")
```

Any help? :)

Comment: Perhaps try to generate predictions on a more denser grid?

Comment: In line with the above comment, ggplot is plotting the data you gave it correctly. If you want "smoother" lines, you'll need to provide it with data that produces the "smoothness" you want. One way, as mentioned, would be to have a denser grid of points to plot. Another might be to interpolate the data you have on a denser grid of points.

Answer (score 2):

The main series is approximately linear, and the confidence intervals seem to be following a quadratic shape, so you could do:

```r
data$upper <- predict(nls(CI.upper ~ a * (b + quan_demands)^2 + c, data, 
                          start = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)))

data$lower <- predict(nls(CI.lower ~ a * (b + quan_demands)^2 + c, data, 
                          start = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = 1)))
```

So the plot would just be something like:

```r
ggplot(data = data, aes(x= quan_demands, y = RR)) + 
  geom_point(size = 1, shape = 19, color = "darkblue") + 
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', size = 0.5, colour = "darkblue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower),
              fill = 'deepskyblue4', alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), 
                     breaks = seq(0, 100, 25)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.75, 1.4), 
                     breaks = seq(0, 1.5, 0.2)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 45, color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1, color = "black", linetype = "dashed") +
  theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", size = 1),
        axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
        axis.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 12),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "mm"),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "deepskyblue3", size = 1),
        strip.text.x = element_text(colour = "white", size = 13)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ "title")
```

[image]

If we add points in to show where the actual 95% confidence intervals are, we see this is an excellent fit:

[image]